# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing custom view attribute

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I'm inflating a custom UI view `mySlider`, but a when setting the value of an attribute on the view,

```
mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0
```

the following error is thrown

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code3=2,address=0x10146ce68)
```

Here is the main controller

```
import UIKit
import HGCircularSlider

class ParamsController: BaseController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: CircularSlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0 // this line throws the error
    }

}
```

Here is the [library](https://github.com/HamzaGhazouani/HGCircularSlider) I'm using

What does the error mean and how can I solve it?

Here is the connections tag in the story board XML

```
<connections>
    <outlet property="mySlider" destination="6QG-AF-AqP" id="tas-EO-CAj"/>
    <outlet property="view" destination="6QG-AF-AqP" id="PkA-ep-m8D"/>
</connections>
```

**edit**

So I noticed that I hand't declared the module in the drop down menu located underneath the class name menu. The same line results in an error, albeit a different error

```
Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1
```

Yep, looks like I had break points set up I hand't noticed

Comment: Make sure you have connected the IBoutlet in your storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the `connections` tag, looks like the IBoutlet is connected right?

Comment: Then the other possibility is that you haven’t created this view controlller instance form the storyboard;is this the initial view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 It's currently set as my entry point, and the view controller appears to be controlling the view like for example changing the background color successfully

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint?  Is there any more information shown on the crash?  A message should be shown along with the exception detail

Comment: Can you please try this :  `@IBOutlet weak var mySlider: CircularSlider! { didSet { mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0} }` and tell us if you have the same problem ?

Comment: @Paulw11 In additional to not having defined the module in the utilities pane, I had also set up two breakpoints on accident... app seems to run

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not having defined the module in the utilities pane, I had also set up two breakpoints on accident... app seems to run now.